# I need a good tool for running a series of Spring Boot based tools on Docker, where each needs a web page and a database connection

Tags: docker, git, deployment

These are pretty much just tools our support and ops departments need to solve small tasks which crop up as a routine sideeffect of our main business operation. They might need to find all instances of Entity with both Field A and Field B, or change some property in some database without having to go through Ops.

Anyway, I write them in Kotlin on Spring Boot just for speed and I use a different Spring Boot instance on each to avoid dealing with conflicting datasources in a single Spring Boot app. I use Docker just because we all use Docker, so why change now. And Docker-compose for easy deployment.

The problem I have is that I want a single command to git update, rebuild image and restart containers. Or, even better. When one of the tools gets updated, just recreate it and replace the container live.

Obviously I could script this, but it seems like something that would exist already. Is there something out there that's "like" CD, but which doesn't have all the overhead?

I tried Dokku. Didn't like it. Way too complicated for what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

According to me a CI like Jenkins or gitlab should be used to build the docker images when the git code changes. Once this works well, you could start to run some scripts that deploy to an environment (CD). First of all, I would like to emphasize that implementing CI is the highest priority as the docker images seems to be built manually at the moment.

Comment: We already use Jenkins, but not for this, and we're phasing out Jenkins. Someone is going to make a decision on a new CI tool at some point, but in the mean time I just want to get some work done.

Comment: Why are you phasing out Jenkins and why do you not use CI for this?

Comment: Because we don't have a jenkins server for it, and the job is not worth setting up one for.
No idea why we're phasing out jenkins, those decisions are made in another country.